# Keep Excel always minimized

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with some macros and userforms.

I don't want the users to have access to the file itself without a password. They should only be able to see the userform and input data through the userform.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
     For Each ws In Worksheets
          ws.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True 'True allows code to change data.
     Next ws

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
UserForm4.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Whenever we need to use another program or application, it minimizes Excel, but when try to use Excel again, the window is maximized.

Is it possible to keep Excel minimized at all times?

Comment: You are referring to the application (Excel) itself, when changing the `WindowState`. If you enter Excel again, the window will be maximized. Make blank sheet and select this during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of minimizing you could hide the application.

```
Application.Visible = False
UserForm4.Show vbModeless
```

In this way you will only see the userform but you have to make sure you reset this setting when you leave the userform.

Comment: I would possibly suggest `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` instead, in case you have multiple Workbooks in the same Application instance

Comment: This should work as well. I think it will depend on the Op's needs.

Comment: @Storax the only problem with `Application.Visible = False` is that then, whenever I change windows, Excel doesn't show up on the taskbar.

Comment: That's true you have to use Alt-Tab to switch

Comment: @Storax It's alright. I guess it works as long as the UserForm doesn't minimize. I ran some tests and this seems like the best solution, since people won't be able to see Excel even if they try to bypass the password. Thank you for your help. :D